# Show that the vector family $(\sin \ell x)$ with $\ell \in \mathbb R$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Can we show it using Lagrange polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Suppose you have a finite sequence of such functions such that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i \sin \ell_i x\equiv 0$$

Then consider the Taylor expansion at order $1$. What relation does it yield?
Differentiate and use again the Taylor expansion. And again, and again.

Do you recognize a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) somewhere? When does its determinant equal zero?